# Formatting and comparing dates and times using Moment JS

Tags: jquery, momentjs

Trying to understand moment js but struggling....

I have a start and end dates & times
I have 4 text input types, will have values as such

Start Date: 13-Nov-2015
Start Time: 2:00 PM

End Date: 13-Nov-2015
End Time: 3:00 PM

I want to do two things, 
1. ensure dates are dates (valid)
2. check to ensure End Date & time is not before Start Date & Time

```
var startDateTime = moment(startDate + startTime).format("D-MMM-YYYY h:mm A")
var endDateTime = moment(endDate + endTime).format("D-MMM-YYYY h:mm A")
```

however if I do 
`alert(startDateTime) I just get "invalid date"

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Print `startDate + startTime` in your browser console, then go to the moment documentation and see if what you got looks like a format that it supports. It doesn't.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ may be helpfull

Comment: `startDate + startTime` you forget the space `+' '+` between no ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow Blag's advice on the validity of your dates...

Concerning question 2 you need to utilize moment's `isBefore` method like so:

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2010-12-31', 'year'); // false
moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2011-01-01', 'year'); // true
```

This is directly from the docs: [isBefore](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the pattern in 2nd parameter of the moment() I think

```js
startDate = '13-Nov-2015';
startTime = '2:00 PM';
endDate = '13-Nov-2015';
endTime = '3:00 PM';

var startDateTime = moment(startDate +' '+ startTime,"D-MMM-YYYY h:mm A");
var endDateTime = moment(endDate +' '+ endTime, "D-MMM-YYYY h:mm A");

alert(startDateTime.format("D-MMM-YYYY h:mm A"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 var startDate = moment($("#DateString").val()).format("D-MMM-YYYY");
        var endDate = moment($("#DateEndString").val()).format("D-MMM-YYYY");
        var endTime = $("#EndTime").val();
        var startTime = $("#StartTime").val();

        var startDateTime = moment(startDate + ' ' + startTime);
        var endDateTime = moment(endDate + ' ' + endTime);
alert(moment(startDateTime).format("D-MMM-YYYY h:mm A"));
```

Comment: you don't need to invoke moment 4 time : `startDate = moment($("#DateString").val()+' '+ $("#StartTime").val(), 'D-MMM-YYYY h:mm A');`  will do the same [as said here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33702157/5546267)